# Как пользоваться MAP-протоколом. Отправка сообщения на SMS-центр

Tags: java, sms, протоколы

Есть MAP-сообщение ([Mobile Application Part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_Application_Part)), которое необходимо доставить в SMS-центр. Как возможно реализовать эту отправку? Может быть через socket? Или с помощью USB-модема с сим-картой? Или как вообще? Адрес SMS-центра очень похож на номер телефона.

Желательно реализовать всё на Java. С C++'ом не разбираюсь.

---

Сообщение `send routing info for sm`, насколько знаю, можно отправлять только с помощью протокола MAP, поэтому именно он мне и нужен. Подскажите, если есть другие протоколы, которые могут отправлять такое же или похожее сообщение.

Comment: Мы отправляем через Kannel (http://www.kannel.org/index.shtml), т.е. из Java приложения по http вызываем Kannel, а он уже обращается в SMS центр провайдера.

Comment: @Russtam, по-моему, Вы единственный, кто на этом форуме что-то про MAP протоколы знает. Kannel точно MAP поддерживает?? Если да, то подскажите, как я эту библиотеку в Java проект подключу и каким образом через HTTP к ней подключусь?

Comment: Извиняюсь что так поздно, на почту не приходило никаких оповещений что мне ответили. Я MAP не знаю, и не знаю точно поддерживает ли Kannel это протокол. Для вызова Kannel по HTTP можно использовать любой ЯП и библиотеку для HTTP, можно даже из браузера (пример см. в разделе "Using the HTTP interface to send SMS messages" http://kannel.org/download/1.5.0/userguide-1.5.0/userguide.html). В природе также существуют различные моды/аддоны для Kannel, может быть там будет для MAP.

Answer (score 2):

Никак. MAP  это сигнальный протокол из стека SS7, обеспечивающий коммуникацию между базовыми станциями и коммутационным центром в пределах одного оператора связи.

За его пределами он никак не используется, и в нормальных условях нет возможности как-то повлиять "человеку со стороны" на передающиеся с его помощью сигналы. Хотя да, есть протокол SCTP являющийся транспортным протоколом IP(наравне с TCP и UDP), позволяющий "заворачивать" внутрь себя SS7, и когда-то давно у некоторых сотовых операторов(в основном на западе) точки подключения к SCTP были выведены напрямую в сеть интернет и были доступны каждому кто о них знал - что повело к ряду "взломов и нештатного использования". Наличие таких операторов сейчас - очень сомнительно.

На оконечных устройствах SS7(и в том числе MAP) не используется, так что "с помощью GSM-модема" в сигнальную линию SS7 вы ничего не отправите.

---

Служебное сообщение "SEND-ROUTING-INFO-FOR-SM" позволяет оператору запросить список идентификаторов базовых станций к которым в данный момент подключен его абонент, а так же дополнительную информацию, позволяющую косвенно определить географическую удаленность устройства от этих базовых станций. Ответ от абонентского устройства поступает в СМС-центр.

Изначально это сообщение разрабатывалось для совсем иных целей, но да, сейчас оно приемущественно используется сотовыми операторами для отслеживания текущего положения абонента по запросу спецслужб.

Если вы не являетесь компанией-оператором абонента или контролирующей его спецслужбой, то:

- Отправить это служебное сообщение вам не удастся - необходимо иметь доступ к комуникационному ядру оператора сотовой связи абонента и/или его базовым станциям, для его отправки с помощью MAP
- Принять ответ на него вы тоже не сможете - необходима возможность чтения служебных сообщений приходящих в SMS-центр оператора
- Ну и интерпретировать ответ от устройства абонента у вас тоже не получится - нужно иметь доступ к базе данных HLR оператора, что бы иметь возможность преобразовать полученые идентификаторы его базовых станций в географические координаты. Узнать достаточно точное положение устройства абонента можно только сопоставив географические кординаты базовых станций и удаленность устройства от них.

Answer (score 1):

В ряде стран получить лицензию моб. оператора и подключится к SS7 не составляет проблем.

Т.е. часть из них сливает возможность соединения(скорей всего не официально), ну поискав в англоязычном интернете найти то что вам надо(**опасайтесь мошенников**, просите тест, платите мелкими сумами).

Насчет законности, я не уверен но наверняка существуют страны где это вполне законно(все на ваш страх и риск).